# What is the difference between a directory and a folder?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Directory vs. Folder](https://superuser.com/questions/169457/directory-vs-folder)

Most people use the terms "folder" and "directory" interchangeably. Is there a difference, and  if so, what is it?

Comment: I am specifically talking of the developer point of view.

Comment: @mafutrct: no difference whether talking from a developer's or user's point of view as far as I know.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191381/english-ui-terminology-directory-or-folder/1195096#1195096 so I do think this is both suited for SO and different from a user POV.

Comment: This really needs to be migrated back to SO.

Comment: ... This question needs to be migrated back to SO instead of being closed as a dupe of a question on SU that even got a wrong answer accepted.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Most of the times they are interchangeable terms. Directory is a classical term used since the early times of file systems while folder is a sort of friendly name which may sound more familiar to Windows users.

The main difference is that a folder is a logical concept that does not necessarily map to a physical directory. A directory is an file system object. A folder is a GUI object. [Wikipedia explains it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_%28computing%29) this way:

> The name folder, presenting an analogy
>   to the file folder used in offices,
>   and used originally by Apple Lisa,
>   is used in almost all modern operating
>   systems' desktop environments. Folders
>   are often depicted with icons which
>   visually resemble physical file
>   folders.
>
> Strictly speaking, there is a
>   difference between a directory which
>   is a file system concept, and the
>   graphical user interface metaphor that
>   is used to represent it (a folder).
>   For example, Microsoft Windows uses
>   the concept of special folders to help
>   present the contents of the computer
>   to the user in a fairly consistent way
>   that frees the user from having to
>   deal with absolute directory paths,
>   which can vary between versions of
>   Windows, and between individual
>   installations.
>
> If one is referring to a container of
>   documents, the term folder is more
>   appropriate. The term directory refers
>   to the way a structured list of
>   document files and folders is stored
>   on the computer. It is comparable to a
>   telephone directory that contains
>   lists of names, numbers and addresses
>   and does not contain the actual
>   documents themselves.

Comment: Could you add Raymond's recent blog post? I'll then select this as the answer again.

Comment: @mafutrct I'm not sure about what you want exactly...?

Comment: Just copy the text in my answer and append it to yours :)

Comment: @mafutrct You answer is just fine. There is no need to have all the valuable information in the accepted answer. Furthermore, Raymond Chen may have authoritative opinions inside Microsoft buy they don't own neither words, directory or folder ;-)

Comment: You're right :)

Comment: Want to add your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078676/what-is-the-difference-between-a-directory-and-a-folder, too?

Comment: Well, I'll just CC this, I don't want it to be missing :)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1195096/412486

Answer (score 13):

[Authoritative answer given by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110216-00/?p=11473):

> Windows 95 introduced Windows Explorer
> and along with it the term folder.
> What is the relationship between
> folders and directories?
>
> Some people believe that Windows 95
> renamed directories to folders, but
> it's actually more than that.
>
> Windows Explorer lets you view
> folders, which are containers in the
> shell namespace. Directories are one
> type of folder, namely, folders which
> correspond to file system locations.
> There are other types of folders, such
> as Control Panel or Network
> Neighborhood or Printers. These other
> types of folders represent objects in
> the shell namespace which do not
> correspond to files. In common usage,
> the term virtual folder has been
> applied to refer to folders which are
> not directories. In other words, we
> have this Euler diagram:
>
> (Virtual folders = Folders −
> Directories)
>
> In general, code which manipulates the
> shell namespace should operate on
> folders and items, not directories and
> files, so as not to tie themselves to
> a particular storage medium. For
> example, code which limits itself to
> files won't be able to navigate into a
> Zip file, since the contents of a Zip
> file are exposed in the form of a
> virtual folder.

Comment: The term folder existed since the early 1980s, according to  Alvara G. Vicario's answer. This might be the answer for windows, but there are other systems.

Comment: I think the answers should be combined, as Raymond pictures the idea given in Alvara's answer in practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a computer's file system the terms are synonymous. "Folders" is a common naming convention when referring to directories in the context of graphical user interfaces. "Directories" is a more common term used with console based interfaces.

Comment: And, as a result, API's lean towards "directory". So, for example, .NET has `DirectoryInfo`, not `FolderInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any difference.

The term directory comes from the notion that it's a directory of the files that it contains.

The term folder comes from the analogy of a cardboard folder containing documents.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the technical definition, but I tend to think of a folder as the local/relative name and a directory as the full name.  For example, looking at something like `C:\Documents and Settings\JCoehoorn\My Documents`, `My Documents` would be the folder and `C:\Documents and Settings\JCoehoorn\My Documents` would be the directory.

Comment: Personally, I would call the longer version the `path` to the `directory`.