# Generalized chmod function differentiating between directories and files (i.e.: with find)

Tags: bash, find, chmod, xargs

Is there a generalized bash function available that mimics `chmod` in every aspect, except that it also let's me differentiate between files and directories?

I know there's already numerous examples available, like the following, from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/91938):

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
chmod 755 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type d)
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

...but those are all with hard-coded arguments, and tedious to remember and type out.<sup>1)</sup>

I'd like to generalize it and make it dynamic, so that I will be able to do something like the following, for instance:

```
# for directories
chmod -d <any valid argument list for chmod> # or
chmodd <any valid argument list for chmod>


# for files
chmod -f <any valid argument list for chmod> # or
chmodf <any valid argument list for chmod>
```

I've tried to create a somewhat viable solution myself, but as my bash skills are sub-par and I'm not sure how to parse the correct arguments and insert them into the correct places, it's very crude and limited:

```
function chmodf {
  find . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod "$@"
}

function chmodd {
  find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod "$@"
}
```

What I'd preferably like, of course, is something like the following (pseudo code):

```
function chmodd {
  paths = extract paths from arguments list
  recursive = extract recursive option from arguments list
  otherargs = remaining arguments
  if( recursive ) {
    find <paths> -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod <otherargs>
  }
  else {
    find <paths> -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod <otherargs>
  }
}
```

Are you aware of the existence of such a function/binary already, or can you help me on my way to achieving this goal?

---

<sup>The main reason I want this, is that I find myself regularly needing to recursively set the setgid bit on directories, but not on files. But, as far as I am aware there's no capital letter `g+S` option for chmod.</sup>

---

<sup>1) I'm aware of the unix adagio "Do one thing and do it well", or something to that extent, but to be honest, I can't fathom how, at least to my knowledge, after nearly half a century of the existence of `chmod` and seeing numerous requests for this behavior, `chmod` has not already been amended with this functionality. It seems like such a obvious and appropriate functionality for `chmod` to have.</sup>

Comment: Can't really figure out what you are trying but have you tried to use the capital letters chmod args? For example +x is Executable but +X only applies to directories

Comment: @Itai Yeah, the thing is, I need it for the setgid bit (`g+s`) on directories and I've already tried (`g+S`), but that doesn't work. So that's how I ended up asking this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:

```sh
chmodx() (
   type="$1"
   shift
   cleared=
   marked=
   recursive=
   for a do
      if [ -z "$cleared" ]; then
         set -- -type "$type" -exec chmod
         cleared=y
      fi
      if [ -z "$marked" ]; then
         case "$a" in
         -- )
            set -- "$@" -- {} +
            if [ -z "$recursive" ]; then
               set -- -prune "$@"
            fi
            marked=y
            ;;
         -R|--recursive )
            recursive=y
            ;;
         * )
            set -- "$@" "$a"
            ;;
         esac
      else
         set -- "$a" "$@"
      fi
   done
   if [ -z "$marked" ]; then
      printf '`--'"'"' required\n'
      return 1
   fi
   exec find "$@"
)

alias chmodf='chmodx f'
alias chmodd='chmodx d'
```

The function and aliases turn

```
chmodf  args for chmod  --  starting points
```

into

```
find  points starting  -type f -exec chmod  args for chmod  {} +
```

Similarly `chmodd …` turns into `find … -type d …`.

It's mainly about rearranging arguments. There is almost no parsing. Everything before `--` is treated as `args for chmod`. Everything after `--` is treated as `starting points` for `find`. We don't want to actually run `chmod` recursively, but we may or may not run `find` recursively. Non-recursive operation is performed thanks to `-prune` in the right place. If there is `-R` or `--recursive` in `args for chmod` then it will disappear but `-prune` will not appear.

Notes:

- I think the code is portable. I deliberately avoided using arrays.
- `chmodf` and `chmodd` could be functions. Even then they should call `chmodx` to keep the code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Implementing them as two independent functions is inelegant.
- **`--` is mandatory** because I decided to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). It's certainly possible to tell apart pathnames from other arguments without separating them with `--`. Actually `chmod` does this. It knows its own syntax, all its possible options and such; so everything else must be files to operate on. Embedding this knowledge and functionality in a shell script is [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions). If you really want things to work without `--` then you should rather solve your problem by improving `chmod`, modifying its source.
- There are ways to abuse:

  - My code does not validate `starting points`, so you can inject e.g. `-maxdepth 3` this way (as `3 -maxdepth` because `starting points` become `points starting`).
  - Similarly there is no validation of `args for chmod`. If `args for chmod` include `;` or `{} +` then the `-exec` primary will be terminated early in the line. This allows you to inject more primaries; or to break the whole command by generating invalid syntax.

  While technically possible, such tricks are ugly. If I needed to complicate things, I would definitely prefer to write a `find` command anew.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a more advanced version of my own initial functions:

**files only `chmod` (`chmodf`):**

```
function chmodf {
  local maxdepth='-maxdepth 1'
  local paths=()
  local args=();
  for arg do
    if [[ "$arg" == '-R' ]]; then
      maxdepth=''
    elif [[ -e "$arg" ]]; then
      paths+=("$arg")
    else 
      args+=("$arg")
    fi
  done
  if [ -z "$paths" ]; then
    paths+=('.')
  fi
  set -- ${args[@]}
  find "${paths[@]}" $maxdepth -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod "$@"
}
```

**directories only `chmod` (`chmodd`):**

```
function chmodd {
  local maxdepth='-maxdepth 0'
  local paths=()
  local args=();
  for arg do
    if [[ "$arg" == '-R' ]]; then
      maxdepth=''
    elif [[ -e "$arg" ]]; then
      paths+=("$arg")
    else 
      args+=("$arg")
    fi
  done
  if [ -z "$paths" ]; then
    paths+=('.')
  fi
  set -- ${args[@]}
  find "${paths[@]}" $maxdepth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod "$@"
}
```

The only thing I'm worried about is that some arguments might be ambiguous and erroneously be interpreted as an existing file with `if [[ -e "$arg" ]]; then`. Not sure how this is normally dealt with, even with `getopts`. But other than that, it appears to work as I intended.

Examples:

```
chmodf g+rx ./* # add group read and execute bit to first level files in ./*
chmodf -R g+rx ./* # add group read and execute bit recursively to files in ./*

chmodd g+rx ./* # add group read and execute bit to first level directories in ./*
chmodd -R g+rx ./* # add group read and execute bit recursively to directories in ./*
# etc.
```

Still curious if anybody else has alternative solutions.