# Method to set permissions equal to or less than something like "0740" in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, chmod

I want all files in every user's home directory to be 0740 or less permissive.

Let's say a user has perms like this:

```
-rwxr----- 1 doej users 321 Jan 6 2013 file1.txt
-rwxrwx--- 1 doej users 555 Jan 6 2013 file2.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 doej users 875 Jan 6 2013 file3.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 doej users 875 Jan 6 2013 file4.txt
-rwxr----x 1 doej users 875 Jan 6 2013 file5.txt
-r--r----x 1 doej users 875 Jan 6 2013 file6.txt
-r-------- 1 doej users 875 Jan 6 2013 file7.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 doej users 875 Jan 6 2013 file8.txt
```

I'm looking for the ability to:

- change files like file8.txt to chmod 740
- leave alone files like file7.txt
- change files like file6.txt to chmod 440

Essentially, reduce excessive permissions without adding more permissions.

If I do this, it will add excessive permissions to files which are below the requirements:

```
sudo chmod 0740 /home/*
```

Is there a command to do this? Does it require a bash script?

Comment: You mean like `g-wx,o-rwx`?

Comment: You do NOT want all files to have the execute bit set. Why on earth would you want that on text files? I am sure what ever _other_ agency you are talking about, they will know that text files should not be executable and are far more likely to take action against you for that.

Comment: @Bib While he didn't want to clear the x bit from all files, what he asked wasn't about having it set on all of them either. The `.txt` might be merely an example.

Comment: @Tom Yan, hence the reason for the comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod g-wx,o-rwx …` will remove `wx` for the group and `rwx` for others; it will not alter anything for the user (owner) nor the state of `r` for the group.

Notes:

- Recursive chmod is `chmod -R`, but usually you want to treat directories differently. See [*Generalized chmod function differentiating between directories and [regular] files*](https://superuser.com/q/1630085/432690).
- If you wanted at most `700`, it would be enough to [`chmod` few directories, non-recursively](https://superuser.com/a/1425631/432690).
- IMO changing mode of another user's single file is a potential abuse of trust, it requires consent or a good reason. Massive change is potentially all the more abusive. If the admin did this for my files out of the blue, I would be concerned.
- Users can `chmod` their files later anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is precisely what I was looking for. I understand your concerns, but this is a rigorously compliant environment. If I don't change the permissions, another agency will shut down the server all together.  Users can override, but I will be running it as a cron job (they could run a cron job after my cron job restoring perms, but that is a discussion we'd have to have later). Thanks again!

Comment: @davidhaskins I understand there may be valid reasons. When I write an answer, I do it for general audience, for future users with similar problems and for the OP (here: for you); sometimes in this exact order of significance. :) Maybe in the future admins with less important reasons will read this and reconsider. The note about a potential abuse is mainly for them.

Answer (score 0):

Use
[find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)
with the `perm` argument, defined as:

```
 -perm -mode
          All of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
          Symbolic modes are accepted in this form, and this is
          usually the way in which you would want to use them.  You
          must specify `u', `g' or `o' if you use a symbolic mode.
```

With the parameter `-perm -740` you will search for all files that have
at least 740 permissions, like this:

```
sudo find . -perm -740 -type f -exec chmod 740 {} \;
```

(You will be setting files that have exactly 740 also to 740,
but that's not a problem.)

For more information see
[How to audit permissions with the find command](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/audit-permissions-find).

Comment: Did you miss the word `exactly` in the part of the manual that you have quoted?

Comment: @TomYan: No, I forgot the minus in front of the 740. Fixed. Don't be so hasty to downvote. If not convinced, read the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: The truth is, you *forgot* you quoted the wrong part of the manual too.

Comment: @TomYan: You're a hard person to satisfy. Is everything to your liking now?

Comment: @TomYan The answers provided on stack exchange are posted by volunteers, generally providing their expertise on their own free time. If you start coming down on them for problems in the details I think you will find the source of free advice drying up for your questions. Be gentle in your criticisms.

Comment: @doneal24 So what was the point of the volunteering when the key that makes the answer make sense is considered "detail"? You may as well *just* paste the link of the manual. I might be less "critical". Thank you for your free time, but no thanks, if feeling good because of upvotes / high reps has become the whole point.

Comment: @TomYan You might notice that I post many solutions in comments where they don't add to my rep but will lead others to strengthen their answers. @ harrymc certainly doesn't need the rep boost either. Typos happen - don't kill the messenger when they occur. It's also understood that you should test answers against your particular environment and adjust as necessary.